# Golang cost for casting between int and uint

Tags: go, casting, integer

I'm porting some old C++ code to go which used unsigned integers fairly often. I can understand their use in the C++ to help ensure positive values were only used in certain places.

However I believe there was also some implicit type conversion going on so in the go version I've ended up with code which looks like

```
Node{IsTerminal: true, TerminalNo: uint(RandPostiveIntUpTo(int(fitnessCases.Terminals)))})
```

Which seems a little unnecessary. I'm curious, is there much of a (time) cost to this casting, and am I losing any significant safety by switching to use int everywhere?

Comment: You should generally _not_ use unsigned integers only to ensure positive values, and reserve them for bitwise manipulation, masks, flags, etc., so there really is no safely lost by using ints. Otherwise, there is no "casting" in go, this is a type conversion.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, also see its a conversion

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as typecasting in Go. Only type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    var test uint = 3
    var tmp int
    for i := 0; i < 1000000000; i++ {
        tmp = int(test)
    }
    // Required by the compiler
    fmt.Print(tmp)
    end := time.Now()
    fmt.Print("Time elapsed: ", end.Sub(start))
}
```

Shows how inexpensive it is. Millions of conversions done in less than 3 msecs (my computer is a fairly powerful iMac but you get the point) which is probably mostly going into the iteration cycle rather than the cast.

However, I would encourage you to use ints and play with your logic to ensure the values are correct (e.g. input validation which needs to be done for security reasons anyway).

In C/C++ the type casting was automagic so you did not need to worry to cast between int and uint even though it was happening. In golang, you need to make it explicit but you are in the exact same situation but adding syntax problems.

Comment: Making up the benchmarks when benchmarking is a part of the standard library :-S

Comment: Yeah... I wanted to make it very clear to everyone who is not familiar with it. The code from above is self-contained and goes straight to the point.

Comment: Did you look at the generated code? Conversion between int and uint shouldn’t cost anything

Comment: @JimB literally nothing or a single instruction?

Comment: @zerkms: they literally execute the same instructions. The data is the same, so the type is only relevant to the compiler.